# Floating Div Breaks out on Zoom

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a sidebar with float: left, in that sidebar is a box with some text in it.
Right next to the sidebar is a wrapper that has content in it.
If I zoom in everything gets sized nicely but the sidebar breaks and jumps to the middle of the wrapper if I zoom it to max.
Actually with my navbar, the last item also breaks and appears under the navbar...

Check out a demo here ( sorry if this is not allowed ): http://www.ascendvault.com

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div id="navbar_items">
        <div class="navbar_item"><a href="#">HOME</a></div>
        <div class="navbar_item"><a href="#">GUIDES</a></div>
        <div class="navbar_item"><a href="#">NPC</a></div>
        <div class="navbar_item"><a href="#">ENEMIES</a></div>
        <div class="navbar_item"><a href="#">ITEMS</a></div>
        <div class="navbar_item"><a href="#">SPELLS</a></div>
        <div class="navbar_item"><a href="#">COMMUNITY</a></div> <!-- this falls under #navbar on max zoom -->
    </div>
</div>  
<div id="sidebar"><!-- the sidebar appears on the content_wrapper on max zoom -->
    <div class="side_box"> 
        <div class="side_box_title"><span>VAULT FEED</span></div>
        <div class="side_box_content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="content_wrapper_middle">
        <%content%>
    </div>
    <div id="content_wrapper_bottom">
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navbar {
    height: 30px;
}


.navbar_item {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    float: left;
}

#content_wrapper {
    margin-left: 230px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is lying on your measurements. You are using some margins in `%`, some in `px`, and a width in `px`. At some point, 1% + 200px will be more than the margin of 230px you have for your `#content_wrapper`. Why is that a block without a width? And why not make them all use `%` if you want a responsive site?

Comment: I fixed it with clear:both; below the navbar but the last item is still breaking and navbar height is not increasing.

Edit: all fixed now, had to put margin-left in percent.

Comment: You need to set `overflow:auto;` on your `#navbar_items` as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is the content of the `navbar` overflowing that causes the left floated `sidebar` to "catch" on the overflow and jump over. Making the `navbar` able to handle increased height, or hide the overflow (less desirable), would fix this.

Comment: I added min-height: 30px; to #navbar and it's still doing the same thing. Seems like the navbar refuses to increase in height even though setting height: 60px; solves everything.

Comment: 60px locks it to that height, and when the total width of the left floated elements exceeds the width you've allowed for the nav it spills out into the content area. Stop floating the nav and the bar will increase in height when it needs to.